# Castle Windsor Configuration: Set Order for FromAssembly.InDirectory for Decorators

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, castle-windsor, decorator

I have a Windsor service and two components implementing it:
One being the "real" service, and one being a "proxy" (implemented as a decorator) that routes the call either to the "real" service, or to a webservice.

Now the ideal situation would be that if the proxy DLL was found, the proxy would be used as a decorator.
And if it doesn't exist, all calls would go directly to the "real" service.

I'm currently using "FromAssembly.InDirectory" to register the components, and this works like a charm.
However, I think this only works because the assemblies happen to be named in the correct alphabetic order, so that the "real" service is registered before the "proxy" (decorator).
(Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

This doesn't look very robust to me.
Is there a better way to do it without manually configuring every single component in a config file?

I'd either like a configuration file where I would only list the assemblies in the correct order, and all components from those files would be registered automatically (just like FromAssembly.Named).

Or - and that would be even better - some mechanism that automatically figures out which component is the decorator (after all, it has a dependency on the service it implements, whereas the "real" service doesn't), and which one is the "real service", and then automatically registers them in the correct order.

I could of course implement the latter logic myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

**Edit:**
This is what I have so far.
How can I make sure the default component (the decorator, if there is one, the default component otherwise) gets named, so that the WCF facility can find it by its name?
I mean, I could just add a "Named" call to the decorator part, but what if there are no decorators defined?

```
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        var currDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var webAppBinDir = currDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
        var assemblyDir = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webAppBinDir)) ? webAppBinDir : currDomain.BaseDirectory;

        container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(assemblyDir, Mask))
                   .Where(ImplementsServiceContract)
                   .WithServiceSelect((x, y) => GetServices(x))
                   .ConfigureIf(IsDecorator, c => c.IsDefault(y => IsDecorating(c, y)))
            );
    }

    private static bool ImplementsServiceContract(Type type)
    {
        return GetServices(type).Any();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetServices(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetInterfaces().Where(IsServiceContract);
    }

    private static bool IsServiceContract(Type type)
    {
        var ns = type.Namespace;
        return ns != null && ns.StartsWith(NamespacePrefix) && Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(ServiceContractAttribute));
    }

    private static bool IsDecorator(ComponentRegistration c)
    {
        Type component = c.Implementation;
        return GetServices(component).Any(x => IsDecorating(c, x));
    }

    private static bool IsDecorating(ComponentRegistration c, Type service)
    {
        Type component = c.Implementation;
        return service.Assembly != component.Assembly;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My old approach for this scenario was to register declarators within web.config or dedicated xml file.
Since version 3.1 you can specify a Default component for a given interface: using a naming convention strategy became pretty easy to set decorators as default component, no matter the concrete registrations.

An other approach I use to ensure registration order, not just for decorators, is creating an InstallerFactory so you can easily drive installers execution order.

Sorry if I do not provide any code example... But I'm in vacation right now

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "default component" thing?
Where would I set that?

Comment: Are you talking about "fallback components" ( http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-31.ashx )?
Would this help for decorators?
Could I use that for all components in one call, or would I still need to configure every single component?

Comment: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx search for Component can now "force" being default for its services, without needing to be the first one registered¶

Comment: But shouldn't the decorator be the component that's registered first?
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.de/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-4-how-to.html

The official doc mentions specifying the order using an IHandlerSelector:
http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Decorators.ashx

But I'm not quite sure if this is what I want.

I have one component implementing the service and one decorator (per service - so it could well be 10 decorators in total or so).

All I want is the decorators to "wrap"/decorate the default component without any resolution loops with as little configuration as possible.

Comment: If you really need to implement the decorator pattern, windsor handles it with no extra configurazione to prevent loop issue. The simplest scenario is having 2 component implementing same interface. The decorator implementation Will have as constructor dependency same interface instance. Windsor uses earlier component registered for that interface but the current One to avoid loop issue. IsDefault configuration I suggested you is not for the nested components implementing same interface but for the interface as dependecy for others components

Answer (score 1):

use `IsDefault` for the decorator

[doco](http://stw.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Whats-New-In-Windsor-3&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Component_can_now_force_being_default_for_its_services_without_needing_to_be_the_first_one_registered_6)

If you don't have a reference to that assembly (why not?) then use `.ConfigureIf` and match the type somehow (probably by name)

Comment: Thanks! How would you make this as robust and easy to configure as possible? I would like the decorator to be registered correctly if the containing assembly exists. But FromAssembly.InDirectory relies on alphabetic order, doesn't it? Should I write my own InstallerFactory?

Comment: As per my answer, if you use IsDefault you do no longer need InstallerFactory

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification in your edit, @krzysztof-kozmic ! I have edited my original questions to include a follow-up question. Care to have a look at that as well? :)